# How do I connect a sequelize ORM with express to ElephantSQL postgres instance?

Tags: postgresql, express, orm, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

This is my configuration in express config.json file

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "elcaaklk",
    "password": "oliBfN1v8h7-JPE3_UN3LJeT3-pf10aJ",
    "database":"elcaaklk",
    "host": "postgres://elcaaklk:oliBfN1v8h7-JPE3_UN3LJeT3-pf10aL@drona.db.elephantsql.com/elcaaklk",
    "dialect": "postgres"
  }
```

This is the error I am getting when I type sequelize db:create

> getaddrinfo EAI_FAIL postgres://elcaaklk:oliBfN1v8h7-JPE3_UN3LJeT3-pf10aL@drona.db.elephantsql.com/elcaaklk

The database connections work fine and the pg client is able to connect to the database.

Comment: Your setup appears to be correct, you can connect to Elephant SQL using the database string or specifying the individual options that are required. Your issue however states "getaddrinfo EAI_FAIL" which is indicative of the host or ip address not being resolved. Please review your host, i hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use:

```
  "development": {
    "use_env_variable": "DATABASE_URL",
    "logging": false,
    "dialect": "postgres",
    "dialectOptions": {
      "ssl": {
        "require": true,
        "rejectUnauthorized": false
      }
    }
  }
```

And then I set the environment variable DATABASE_URL to the quoted postgres:// URI

You could also use your method but then you have to set "host" to equal just the host part of the URI (drona.db.elephantsql.com)